# How can I write python regular expression to match multiple space in a row

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this, it has multiple spaces before 'READY' and after 'READY'

All empty space in the following examples are Space

```
'1df34343 43434sebb              READY                     '
```

How can I write a regular expression which can get '1df34343 43434sebb' as result.group(1)?

Comment: Are you having just a single whitespace between `3 and 4` in `..343 434..`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This captures the required group if it is followed by multiple spaces + READY. Uses positive look-ahead.

```
(\S+ \S+)(?=\s{2,}READY)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you understand regular expressions you should know the following:

- `\s` : whitespace characters
- `\S` : non-whitespace characters
- `+`  : at least one of the previous capture.

script:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '1df34343 43434sebb              READY                     '
>>> ms = re.match(r"(\S+ \S+)\s+(\S+)\s+", s)
>>> ms.groups()
('1df34343 43434sebb', 'READY')
>>> ms.group(1)
'1df34343 43434sebb'
>>> ms.group(2)
'READY'
```

you can even have a more functional regex which can be used if you ever need a more detailed parse of what you have:

```
>>> ms = re.match(r"((\S+) (\S+))\s+(\S+)\s+", s)
>>> ms.groups()
('1df34343 43434sebb', '1df34343', '43434sebb', 'READY')
>>> ms.group(1)
'1df34343 43434sebb'
>>> ms.group(2)
'1df34343'
>>> ms.group(3)
'43434sebb'
>>> ms.group(4)
'READY'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple regex that captures everything until it sees two spaces in a row:

```
In [11]: s = '1df34343 43434sebb              READY                     '

In [12]: re.match(r'(.*?)\s\s', s).groups()
Out[12]: ('1df34343 43434sebb',)
```

This captures your requirements as I've understood them. If something is amiss, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Match anything *before* a multi-space group:

```
 re.compile(r'^(.*?)(?:\s{2,})')
```

outputs:

```
>>> import re
>>> multispace = re.compile(r'^(.*?)(?:\s{2,})')
>>> multispace.match('1df34343 43434sebb              READY                     ').groups()
('1df34343 43434sebb',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split your string in 2 or more spaces. You will get a list, from which you can get the first element, which is the one you need. You don't really need a complex regex for that: -

```
>>> s = '1df34343 43434sebb              READY                     '
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[ ]{2,}', s)[0]
>>> '1df34343 43434sebb'
```

Comment: what is the benefit of this? i don't think that this is more efficient than matching, and you lose some functionality in the long run.

Comment: @InbarRose.. Well, I think `split` fits best for the string which OP has posted. It's not that it's good or bad. Even split uses a `regex`. And also, I do love `Regex` myself. But for this particular case, it seems overkill to use build a regex to match complete string, when OP just wants the first part.