# Python Regex to Extract Email Information

Tags: python, regex, email

I Have below data, from this I want to retrieve only the message boy part and remove all the info related to “Forward” header.

```
---------------------- Forwarded by Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT on 03/21/2000 
01:24 PM ---------------------------
 
 
Stephane Brodeur
03/16/2000 07:06 AM
To: Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT@ECT
cc:  
Subject: Maps
 
As requested by John, here's the map and the forecast...
Call me if you have any questions (403) 974-6756.
```

What I have tried so far is below regular expression.
 
matchObjj = re.search(r'(---.*?)Subject:', tmp_text, re.DOTALL)

When I print using below command

```
print( tmp_text[matchObjj.span()[1]:])
```

I get below output.

```
Maps
 
As requested by John, here's the map and the forecast...
Call me if you have any questions (403) 974-6756.
```

So basically the issue is that the regex is not stripping the complete line of “Subject:” and only the header Subject: is removed but the actual subject text is still there which in this case is “Maps”.
 
I want the regex to detect the text till end of Subject line and then remove it. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way should be to change your regex to this:

```py
r'(---.*?)Subject:[^\n]*\n'
```

This will make your match extend all the way to the next newline, making the end of its span the start of the next line.

Comment: @AsadKamal then please accept as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regex by creating a list of sentences with `splitlines` and slicing this list from the Subject line:

```
text = '''---------------------- Forwarded by Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT on 03/21/2000 
01:24 PM ---------------------------
 
 
Stephane Brodeur
03/16/2000 07:06 AM
To: Phillip K Allen/HOU/ECT@ECT
cc:  
Subject: Maps
 
As requested by John, here's the map and the forecast...
Call me if you have any questions'''

data = text.splitlines()
slice_idx = [i for i, s in enumerate(data) if s.startswith('Subject: ')][0]
body = '/n'.join(data[slice_idx+2:])
```

output:

```
As requested by John, here's the map and the forecast...
Call me if you have any questions
```

Comment: RJ reason i m using regex is because one email thread can contain multiple forward blocks and using the slicing will become difficult with multiple forward block in same email thread.

Answer (score -1):

There are more spaces after the subject line, or maybe there is \t separation for your case. You can try to match the case with two or more spaces. e.g.

```
regexEquation = "(---.*?)Subject:[^\n]*(\s)+"
```

You can get help for matching more spaces from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602762/how-can-i-write-python-regular-expression-to-match-multiple-space-in-a-row) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610129/regex-to-match-more-than-2-white-spaces-but-not-new-line/5610133).

```
**Output**: As requested by John, here's the map and the forecast...
Call me if you have any questions (403) 974-6756.
```

Comment: UPD: It will not give you the required result, the answer by @rkechlos will work fine.